# Pylint mis-identifies typing of decorated method

Tags: python, pylint

I have a decorator for a data class that looks something like this:

```
def dictionary_updater(key):

    # Create the actual decorator method and return it
    def inner(func):

        # Create the method that should actually be called when the decorated function is invoked
        def with_dict(self, payload):
            payload[key] = func(self)
        return with_dict
    return inner
```

What this lets me do is modify a class method so that it sets the key on a dictionary associated with the decorator to the value returned by the method. I use it like this:

```
@dataclass()
class Search:
    _search_start: date
    _search_end: date

    @dictionary_updater('DTO-START')
    def search_start(self) -> str:
        return f'{self._search_start.year}{self._search_start.month:02}'

    @dictionary_updater('DTO-END')
    def search_end(self) -> str:
        return f'{self._search_end.year}{self._search_end.month:02}'
```

I can then instantiate a `Search` and use it to populate a dictionary:

```
payload = {}
search = Search(datetime(2023, 6, 22).date, datetime(2023, 7, 23).date)
search.search_start(payload)
search.search_end(payload)

payload # {'DTO-START': '202306', 'DTO-END': '202307'}
```

Pylint doesn't complain about this either, unless I use it in a test file. For reference, my  project directory looks like this:

```
data.py           (where the decorator and Search are located)
scraper.py        (where I actually create the dictionary)
test/
- test_data.py    ERROR
```

And, my test code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytest

from data import Search

def test_payload_updated():
    payload = {}
    search = Search(datetime(2023, 6, 22).date, datetime(2023, 7, 23).date)
    search.search_start(payload) # Error
    search.search_end(payload)   # Error
```

And, what pylint complains about:

> Too many positional arguments for method call

It seems that pylint doesn't "see" the decorator, so I attempted to write the code as a class method:

```
def to_payload(self, payload):
   self.search_start(payload)
   self.search_end(payload)
```

and now I'm getting a different error from pylint:

> Too many positional arguments for method call

So, it seems that pylint assumes that the method takes `self` and returns a `str` rather than taking `self` and a `dict` and returning nothing. According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/3954), this appears to be an error with pylint. Is there a way to deal with this apart from ignoring it?